# Show only one div in main page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a project for my school, and I need a main page where I can display all my different divs, but only one at a time and always show one. I dont understand much of js, but I got that code who does the job, but if I click the same button it will hidde it, and I dont want to close it, just to stay in the same div.

It will act upon itself, my main page.

HTML:

```
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('home');">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('forms');">Forms</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
div.content {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding: 1px 16px;
    height: 1000px;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var divState = {};
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
        for (var div in divState){
            if (divState[div] && div != id){
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
                divState[div] = false;
            }
        }
        divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
    }
}
```

Comment: please define *"reload it"* in more specific terms

Comment: Are you looking for something like a fade out, followed immediately by a fade in?

Comment: It would be ideal if your HTML example contained the elements the JavaScript and CSS will act upon; please consider adding this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st use `var divState = ['home', 'forms'];` hold all your div.

2nd when you click hide all other div, show the clicked one.

3rd call `showhide('home')` on page load.

```css
div.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('home');">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('forms');">Forms</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="home">
  home div
</div>
<div id="forms">
  forms div
</div>


<script>
  var divState = ['home', 'forms'];

  function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
      var divid = document.getElementById(id);

      for (var d in divState) {
        if (divState[d] != id) {
          document.getElementById(divState[d]).style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          divid.style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  showhide('home');
</script>
```

Comment: I want it to not close the div if i press it again and to show Home on first page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the div on click, but not hide it when the same link is clicked again, just replace the last line of the `showHide()` function to always show the div instead of toggling it.

```
var divState = {};
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
        for (var div in divState){
            if (divState[div] && div != id){
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
                divState[div] = false;
            }
        }
        divid.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I make it to show a div on page load? As it is blank the first time it shows

Comment: Just call `showhide('home')` on page load to show the home page when the page has loaded.